# .current class not changing when i click on pagination in WordPress site

Tags: php, css, wordpress, pagination

I do not find any way to solve this type of error.I have added a pagination on my wordpress site.All things are ok.But when i click on 2,3,4...etc page it does not change its class `.current` thats why it does not get the css of `.current` class.

**function code for gallery:**

```
function jellythemes_gallery($atts, $content=null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit' => -1
        ), $atts ) );
    global $post;
    $back=$post;
    echo '<div id="portfolio">
                <div class="section portfoliocontent">
                    <section id="i-portfolio" class="clear">';

      // set up or arguments for our custom query
      $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
      $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'media',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'paged' => $paged
      );
      // create a new instance of WP_Query
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                $image = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_media_photo', true );
                $video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jellythemes_media_video', true );
                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'media_thumb');

                echo '<div class="ch-grid element">
                                <img class="ch-item" src="' . $img[0] .'" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
                if (empty($video)) {
                    echo '<a class="fancybox img-lightbox" rel="" href="' . $img[0] .'">';
                } else {
                    echo '<a class="fancybox-media" rel="" href="' . $video.'">';
                }
                echo '<div>
                        <span class="p-category ' . (empty($video) ? 'photo' : 'video') . '"></span>
                          </div>
                            </a>
                            </div>';
     endwhile; 

             $post=$back; //restore post object
    $return .= '</section>
            </div>
        </div>';

    echo "<div class='pagination_center'>";
     if ($the_query->max_num_pages > 1) { 
                $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

                echo paginate_links(array(
                    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                    'format' => '/page/%#%',
                    'current' => $current_page,
                    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                    'show_all'  => true,
                    'prev_text' => __('« PREV'),
                    'next_text' => __('NEXT »'),
                    'prev_next' => false,
                ));
    }

     else{ 
      echo '<article>
        <h1>Sorry...</h1>
        <p>';echo 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'; echo'</p>
      </article>';
    }
     endif; 
    echo "</div>";

    return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'jellythemes_gallery', 'jellythemes_gallery' );
```

**css:**

```
.pagination_center .current{
border: 1px solid #c3121c;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #c3121c;
}
```

Here i added an [**image**](http://prntscr.com/c8t6bk) with inspect element.It is page 2 but `.current` class on page 1.Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Thanks in advance.If you need further any code please let me know.

Comment: can you show us pagination code plz

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud : where is the JS code where you adding the class?

Comment: can you read answers here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126080/changing-pagination-list-class

Comment: @YoYo i think `.current` is the wordpress class.I have not add any js for this class.

Comment: can you paste the function for onclick of 2, 3, 4, etc ?

Comment: @YoYo its a wordpress .. it has its own rules by adding some css using its own functions..

Comment: @Mit.agile : but how we will will know if `current` class is indeed getting added in onclick function

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud did u follow the above link which i sent you ? in that link there a code given by a user who got 4 upvotes but not marked as best answer. Try to paste that code in your theme just to check to see atleast you are able to append your current class or not.

Comment: @Mit.agile i have check.But this is not working at all.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same problem and fixed it debugging my pagination code.
Here is the solution for the pagination to work in a static front page.
Replace

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

with

```
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
}
else {
    $paged = 1;
}
```

in your WP_Query loop.

Then you need to replace

```
'current' => $current_page,
```

with

```
'current'      => max( 1, $paged ),
```

in your paginate_links array.

In my case, it worked like a charm. You should also try this. I am sure it will work 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your base for next page. Possibly the issue may be `%_%` and `%#%` and without testing it seems to be less helpful. But try the below code,

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link($big) ) ),
    'format' => '/page/%#%',
    'current' => $current_page,
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'show_all' => true,
    'prev_text' => __('« PREV'),
    'next_text' => __('NEXT »'),
    'prev_next' => false,
));
```

It may help you. Also refer more for [Paginate Links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Comment: I have tested but not working. `.current` class is in the page 1.Not changing at all.

Comment: What is the value of `$current_page` after line `$current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));` Is it incremented or not.

Comment: pagination changes its value but do not change the class `.current` one to another.

Comment: I have seen your site. You need to debug it yourself by using print_r for the array which your are passing in `paginate_links` function for each page.